# Magento 1.9 RWD Theme - 3-Column-Layout

Tags: magento, navigation, themes

I want a 3-Column-Layout in my Magento 1.9 RWD Theme, but it doesn't work if I change it in the backend. I'm still having a 2-Column-Layout.

Is a 3-Column-Layout in the RWD Theme even possible?

Is there a solution to this? Changing the catalog.xml directly?

Comment: Have you flushed cache?

Comment: Cache is deactivated. It seems like the problem isn't a missing 3rd column, but the possibility of using a vertical navigation.

I'm trying to remove the top (horizontal) category navigation and have it on the left side, because there are a lot of categories.

Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok first of all check your chache... it supports the 3 column lay out as i have done it my self.

just enter the below code in xml where you want to edit:

```
<[module]_[controller]_[function]>
   <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
   </reference>

</[module]_[controller]_[function]>
```

change [module]*[controller]*[function] to your url which you want to enter the 3 column layout.

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: Well thanks a lot. Unfortunately it seems like I'm not missing the 3-Column-Layout, but the ability to move the top Navigation to the left Side of the page.

Seems like I got confused and thought that I don't have a 3rd Column.

Have you done this also? Moving the TOP Navigation to the Left side? (horizontal to vertical)

Comment: Okk here what you can do that make an local.xml in layout folder. Or you can go directly into your page.xml and remove <block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks"/> from the header block and add it to the block left_first or left as you like it. cher... Also you can find help on  : http://www.vjtemplates.com/blog/magento/removing-and-moving-top-links

Comment: None of those suggestions worked. I can't explain myself why the page won't change. I'm in the right directory, editing the right files, and the cache is disabled. What could it be..?